# Notation question: Multiplying probability measure by a nonnegative function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, notation

Suppose $P$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, and $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}_+$ is a nonnegative function.

I define a new measure, given by:

$$Q(A) = \int_A f(\omega) \, dP(\omega), \quad A \in \mathcal{F}.$$

This is a (nonnegative) measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}$), provided $f$ is measurable. Is there a standard notation for this? I am familiar with the notion of push forward, but this is not quite that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation is typically $dQ = fdP$, or sometimes $f = \frac{dQ}{dP}$.  $f$ is called the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $Q$ with respect to $P$.

Comment: While I agree that $f$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative, I was just wondering if there was a compact notation for $Q$ without writing $Q$ is such that $dQ/dP = f$.

Comment: Something like "Let $dQ = fdP$" or "Define $Q$ by $dQ = fdP$" should both be pretty clear.